Late 90's/early 2000's movie where a possibly American mother starts having visions of herself in a past life in early 20th century Ireland
Help me find this title please :)
A movie from the late 90's/early 2000's. The main character is a middle aged - possibly American - mother of a teenage son, who starts having visions of herself as a women living with an abusive husband and several young children in the early-midd 20th century in the small town of Malahide, Ireland.
She draws pictures of some of the land marks and places in her visions. She travels to Ireland with her son to get answers and meets the eldest son of her vision self.

Yesterday's Children with Jane Seymour from 2000.

Jenny Cole lives with her husband and son in middle America. She is pregnant and starts to have very vivid dreams about a small city that has a big church. She then starts talking to her mother about it and her mother shows her some drawings she made when she was a child. To her amazement they are identical to the drawings from her dreams that she is now having. Jenny and her mother do research and find that the dreams are about a small town called Malahide in Ireland in the 1930s. The mother gives Jenny, her son and her husband tickets to go to Ireland, so that she can find out about her dreams. Had Jenny lived in the past after all as Mary Sutton?

Here's a video with some clips from the movie:



